# How to make a Label with Transparent BackColor in VB.NET? The text overlaps with something else

Tags: arrays, vb.net, label

When I use *LabelAngle(i).BackColor = Color.Transparent* something else show up.

![LabelAngle(i).BackColor = Color.Transparent][1]

```
                LabelAngle(i) = New Label
                LabelAngle(i).Parent = canvas
                LabelAngle(i).AutoSize = True
                LabelAngle(i).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.DodgerBlue
                LabelAngle(i).Location = New System.Drawing.Point(Xstart(i) - 30, ReferenceY - BarHeight)
                LabelAngleValue(i) = 180 - randAngle(i)
                LabelAngle(i).Text = LabelAngleValue(i).ToString + "°"
                LabelAngle(i).TextAlign = ContentAlignment.BottomLeft
                LabelAngle(i).BackColor = Color.Transparent
                LabelAngle(i).BringToFront()
```

Comment: Windows Forms doesn't really support true transparency.  When you set the `BackColor` to `Transparent`, the background of the control actually shows a snapshot of its `Parent` behind it, even if there's another in between.  That's the way it is.

Comment: Set the label's .parent property to the control that you want to show through.  The default is the form itself.

Answer (score 5):

Just type the colour code `16777215` into the BackColour property

Answer (score 3):

To make a label transparent you need to set the forms transparencykey to lets say maroon "or a color you never will use".

[image]

Then if you set the label Backcolor to Maroon it will be transparent.

"But it will never show the control under it"

Comment: That's only for top level forms.

Answer (score 0):

Double click in your Form and type this *(this worked for me)*:
Ex:

```
Private Sub formName_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    labelName.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As several people have noted on here, transparency is relative to the parent object; meaning that instead of truly becoming transparent, your object's backcolor will be set to match its parent object.

Another important thing to note, when you change a parent relationship, the child's location becomes based upon the location of the parent. This was a problem I was having for sometime. When I tried to change the parent of my object, my object kept disappearing, until I realized that it was really being moved off screen because its location was based upon the parent and I was setting it based upon the form.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).